# Enable a default disabled button - PHP, HTML, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I really need help.

I am trying to have a setup wherein an admin could enable a client's button that is disabled by default.

So far, I have this code below for the admin. It updates the value column (0 by default) in the button table in the database. And this part is successful.

```
<input name="enable1"  type="submit"   id="button" value="Enable Button" />


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['enable1'])){           
    mysql_query("UPDATE button SET value = '1' WHERE cat_no = 'cat1'"); }
?>
```

And the code for the user is written below. My plan is that, when the admin updates the column value into 1, the code below will echo the enabled button, as by the default, the button is disabled.

And this part is a failure, it does not enable the disabled button. And I noticed, that the first echo in the if statement doesn't work, the only thing that is working is the echo in the else statement where the button is disabled.

```
<?php 

    $sql="SELECT value FROM button WHERE cat_no = 'cat1'";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result == '1'){
    echo '<input name="enable2"  type="submit" class="inputDisabled"        

        id="button"  value="Proceed to Next Category" />' ;}

else {

    echo '<input name="enable2"  type="submit" class="inputDisabled"        

        id="button"  disabled="disabled"  value="Proceed to Next Category" />';}                            
 ?>
```

I also tried to search for alternatives like jQuery. But I can't make it work. And if possible, when the admin clicks the button, the user's page will refresh automatically.

Please help. I really need guidance. Thank you.

Comment: what's failing with it?

Comment: Primarily, it does not enable the disabled button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Try this :

```
<?php 

    $sql="SELECT value FROM button WHERE cat_no = 'cat1'";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result= mysql_result($result,0,"value"); // I added this line
if ($result == '1'){
    echo '<input name="enable2"  type="submit" class="inputDisable"        

        id="button"  value="Proceed to Next Category" />' ;}

else {

    echo '<input name="enable2"  type="submit" class="inputDisabled"        

        id="button"  disabled="disabled"  value="Proceed to Next Category" />';}                            
 ?>
```

Is there only one client ? If not how will you check which client's button is enabled and which is not ?

Comment: There are only 5 users. If the admin enables the button, all of the buttons of the users will be enabled altogether.

Comment: Oh my biscuit! It works! Thank you very much. Another one. Do you know how to refresh the user's page automatically when an admin pushes a button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $sql="select count(*) as total from button where cat_no = 'cat1'";
    $runsql=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_die());
    $data=mysql_fetch_object($runsql);
        if($data->total==1){
        echo '<input name="enable2"  type="submit" class="inputDisabled" id="button"  value="Proceed to Next Category" />';
        }
        else {
    echo '<input name="enable2"  type="submit" class="inputDisabled"
            id="button"  disabled="disabled"  value="Proceed to Next Category" />';}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But there's a parse error in the second line. It says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$runsql' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: yes because i forgot to add semicon in my 1st line. now added hope it help you.

Comment: Yes. I thought it has the same variables. What should I edit then?

Comment: no need to do something with variable just i have add a semicolon (;) in first line